# What is the best way to group similar columns in a dataset

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have a datasets with many columns (from 16 to 2500 columns)

I have built a similarity function that rates the percentage of how similar these columns are.

Example:

```
ID    Toyota   Apple   BMX   Tesla   Orange   Samsung   Cat   BitCoin   Lucy
1      0       1       1     0       1        0         1     1         1
2      1       0       1     0       0        0         1     0         1
3      1       1       0     1       1        1         0     0         1
...
```

I have identified the similarity between these columns like this:

```
First Column      Second Column     Similarity Percentage
Apple             Samsung           0.97
Toyota            Tesla             0.95
Toyota            Orange            0.89
Toyota            BMX               0.88
Apple             Orange            0.84
Orange            Lucy              0.83
Lucy              BitCoin           0.79
Orange            Cat               0.78
.                 .                 .
.                 .                 .
.                 .                 .
Apple             Cat               0.24
```

I would like to group these into most similar groups:

```
Group A : Apple, Samsung, 

Group B : Toyota, Tesla, BMX

Group C : Orange, Lucy, BitCoin, Cat
```

Where these groups have the closest optimized matched columns together.

Is there any algorithm or method that solves this problem?